# Exception when adding multiple editors inside react component using react hook and configured menu

Tags: wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

Any one else ever try adding multiple milkdown editors on one react page ?
I am getting this error? My menu is configured as a constant and am passing it in the hook on component initialization. I don't get what is wrong here ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQvDs.png)

```
const configuredMenu = menu.configure(menuPlugin, {
    config: [
        [
            {
                type: 'select',
                text: 'Heading',
                options: [
                    { id: '1', text: 'Large Heading' },
                    { id: '2', text: 'Medium Heading' },
                    { id: '3', text: 'Small Heading' },
                    { id: '0', text: 'Plain Text' },
                ],
                disabled: (view) => {
                    const { state } = view
                    const setToHeading = (level: number) => setBlockType(state.schema.nodes.heading, { level })(state)
                    return !(setToHeading(1) || setToHeading(2) || setToHeading(3))
                },
                onSelect: (id) => (id ? [TurnIntoHeading, Number(id)] : [TurnIntoText, null]),
            },
        ],

    ],
})

export const MilkdownEditor = ({ taskId, taskField, value }: MilkdownEditorProps) => {
    let markdown = ''
    const { editor, loading, getInstance } = useEditor((root, renderReact) => {
        return Editor.make()
            .config((ctx) => {
                ctx.set(rootCtx, root)
                ctx.set(defaultValueCtx, isEmpty(value) ? 'markdown editor' : value)
                ctx.get(listenerCtx).markdownUpdated((_, value) => {
                    markdown = value
                })
                ctx.get(listenerCtx).blur((ctx) => {
                    patchTaskField(taskId, taskField.processRecordMetadata.id, {
                        [toFieldKey(taskField.field)]: markdown,
                    })
                })
            })
            .use(nord)
            .use(commonmark)
            .use(tooltip)
            .use(listener)
            .use(configuredMenu)
    })

    return <ReactEditor key={taskField.processRecordMetadata.id} editor={editor} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed by milkdown@6.3.2.